# How to show javac Warnings in Problems view in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac, compiler-warnings, intellij-14

In Eclipse the Problems View displays javac errors + javac warnings, whereas in IntelliJ I get only the errors. While warnings are highlighted when editing a file, I would like to have a list of all the warnings in the Project.

Is there an option to configure exactly that or a plugin providing such a View?

I am not looking for the Inspection View. The Inspection view does not automatically update like the Problems view does when I enable auto make the project.

I am also not looking for the Message View. The Message View also does not automatically update like the Problem view does when I enable auto make. Also the message view is more like a visually more appealing variant of running javac in terminal. The list items in the message view do not act like items in the Problems view.

Comment: I don't know a method to show warnings in the *Problems View*. But you can `Build > Rebuild Project` which will open the *Messages View*, which shows warnings (unless `Hide Warnings` is enabled in the left panel). However, this view won't get updated by the automatic make.

Comment: I know about the Message View, but it does not cut it the same way the Problems View with Warnings would (as you say) – but thanks for pointing it out. I read that recommendation a lot in blogs/other forums. I clarified my question accordingly.

Comment: If there's one area where Eclipse is superior, it is the incremental compiler. That's the advantage of relying on your own compiler, dedicated to the integration with the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. Write a plugin or use another IDE.